# Slope of a line in 2D Co-ordinates

Tags: linear-algebra

Does the slope depend on how the `y` of a straight line changes or on both x and y?

For example, A straight line `2x - y = 0` passing through origin has a slope `m = 2`.

Now, when

```
x = 1  |  y = 2
x = 2  |  y = 4
x = 3  |  y = 6
```

It looks like the value of `y` is increasing by 2, which is confusing me because `m = 2`.

In **case 2**, A straight line `2x + 3y = 18` has slope m = `-2/3`

and, when

```
x = 1 | y = 5.33
x = 2 | y = 4.66
x = 3 | y = 4
```

In this case it looks like the `y` is decreasing by `-2/3`

so, does the slopes of a straight line only effect `y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slope of the straight line is only affecting y in your case because you are deciding to measure y and not x, i.e. you are setting the values of x and calculating the values of y from there.

If you were to draw y = 2x while measuring y (that is, you are setting the values of y and calculating the values of x) you would find that x increases by 1/2 (i.e. 1/m).

```
y = 1 | x = 0.5
y = 2 | x = 1.0
y = 3 | x = 1.5
```

So in actuality m effects whichever value you are calculating, as you are setting the other value yourself (you're affecting the other value)

Answer (score 0):

The slope of a straight line here is the change in $y$ divided by the change in $x$.  Your equation can be written as $y = 2x$ and, as your numbers show, each increase of $x$ by 1 leads to an increase in $y$ by 2.

Draw the lines $y = 2x$ and $y = x$ on co-ordinate axes with the $x$-axis horizontal and $y$-axis vertical, and you will see that the line with a larger slope is steeper.

**Added later:** On your second added question, you have correctly worked out the slope as close to $-2/3$. But this is not just the change in $y$.  If you had only the data

```
x = 1 | y = 5.33
x = 3 | y = 4
```

then the change in $y$ would be $-1.33$, but the change in $x$ would be $2$.  You have to divide one by the other. So the slope would be $-1.33/2 \approx -2/3$, as before.